# Is there a drag-and-drop style gui builder for Kivy? (the same way visual studio

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

im just wondering is there a drag and drop gui builder for kivy? Like you drag the elements you want and it generates the .kv file for you. From what I understand kivy uses mainly a automatic layout method, but i want to be able to fine tune the location. And adjusting coord to re run is extreamly time consuming. Im looking for something similar to VisualTK for tinker.

Thanks